# Linked List insert in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have recently started working with linked lists. To push an element into linked list in the insert(...) function, I saw we always check if(head == NULL) but it occurs only once.

I want to know if there is any way so that we can avoid the unnecessary check always. Please suggest something that would be relevant to most of the linked list operations. One solution I figured out is that writing a new function "add_first_element(....)" so that explicitly we add the first element and then other elements are added in a generic way.

I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way is to use a sentinel node. That is, a node that contains no useful data, but merely serves as the placeholder for the one *before* the first node. This way you don't need to check for null.

For double-linked list, you will need two sentinel nodes to avoid null checking.

Comment: Thank you... @C.R. but that may sometimes cost memory.... isn't there any other alternative which do not consume memory?

Comment: @JagannathSuhit: The memory of one node is just a fraction of that of the whole linked list, unless you use linked list for just several objects (in which case array is better from any aspect).